# WebChromeClient open app in chrome browser.I want to open it in WebView.What's the solution for that

Tags: webview, webclient, webchromeclient

WebChromeClient open app in chrome browser.I want to open it in WebView.I used WebChromeClient for KitKat devices and for other WebViewClient used. What's the solution for that?

Comment: any help.I am stuck at that issue and icon looks different in KitKat devices.works well on other devices